# error: cannot find symbol when using .setFont()

Tags: java, swing, try-catch, truetype, cannot-find-symbol

I've been trying to use a custom font (included in the package) in my Swing application. I've seen many snippets of code and tutorials on this topic, but I can't seem to get it to work. 
After narrowing thirteen errors down to one, I may have modified the code into something that doesn't quite do what I want it to do. Unfortunately, I'm just starting to learn Java and I can't figure it out. Below is my code, and after that is my error. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you so much!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;

public class welcomeWindow extends JFrame {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new welcomeWindow();
  }
  public welcomeWindow() {
    // opens window to specifications
    Toolkit toolkit=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    this.setSize(toolkit.getScreenSize().width, toolkit.getScreenSize().height);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("window title");
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    // creates panel, adds panel to frame
    JPanel welcomePanel = new JPanel();
    this.add(welcomePanel);

    // font (where i THINK the problem may be)
    try {
        Font childTitle = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream("comic_andy.ttf")).deriveFont(30f);
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream("comic_andy.ttf")));
    } catch (IOException | FontFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Font childTitle = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 30);
        System.err.println("caught error");
    }

    // creates title label and adds to panel
    JLabel welcomeTitle = new JLabel("title");
    welcomeTitle.setFont(childTitle);
    welcomePanel.add(welcomeTitle);

  }
}
```

As stated earlier, here is the error I'm getting (quite simple, really):

```
welcomeWindow.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
    welcomeTitle.setFont(childTitle);
                         ^
  symbol:   variable childTitle
  location: class welcomeWindow
1 error
```

I've been thinking that I didn't create the font correctly, but I'm assuming I'm wrong as I can't fix the problem. If someone could point me in the direction of where my code is going wrong, that would be AMAZING. Thank you!

Comment: That variable is defined in a try-catch  block, you can not see it outside.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `myFont` is declared local to the `try..catch` block. Move it outside the block.

```
Font myFont;
try {
    myFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream("comic_andy.ttf")).deriveFont(30f);
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream("comic_andy.ttf")));
} catch (IOException | FontFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    myFont = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 30);
    System.err.println("caught error");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! When I try this, it tells me that ' variable myFont is already defined in constructor welcomeWindow()'

Comment: @badcoder Your post doesn't show that. Maybe you didn't post the entire thing? If that is the case, just rename it to something else then

Comment: I tried to do that but it still gives me the same message. Here's where myFont is defined:
welcomeWindow.java:30: error: variable childTitle is already defined in constructor welcomeWindow()
        Font myFont= Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream("comic_andy.ttf")).deriveFont(30f);

Comment: It is complaining about `childTitle` and not `myFont`. Check if you declared `childTitle` more than once. You haven't shown `childTitle` in your code.

Comment: Oh, I changed childTitle to myFont on the code. I forgot to change some of the text, my bad.

Comment: welcomeWindow.java:30: error: variable childTitle is already defined in constructor welcomeWindow()
        Font childTitle = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream("comic_andy.ttf")).deriveFont(30f);
             ^
welcomeWindow.java:35: error: variable childTitle is already defined in constructor welcomeWindow()
        Font childTitle = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 30);

(full updated error message)

Comment: Still, your code `welcomeTitle.setFont(myFont);` and your error message `welcomeTitle.setFont(childTitle);` do not agree. I hope you get the idea of why this error is happening and how to fix it.